# CSS only technique to make dynamic div height, expandable to contend outside of it

Tags: css, height

I am building a web site for home made jewelry. I'd like it nice and centered ( for all those ppl with low resolution ) so all of the titles, navigation and content are in a single div, that I positioned in the center. On the left ( inside the div, everything is inside the div ) I have my vertical navigation sidebar div. On the right I have the title and the content. So far so good. Now to the problem:

I would like my sidebar to have a right border all the way from the top of the page to the bottom ( with 1em margins if possible ). The trick is that my content to the right variate from text to pictures and forms and is quite different on every page - when the content is larger then the screen the screen scrolls and in which case I'd like my sidebar border to scroll down with it - I've not been able to do that.

I think I have done quite a reading - my closest solution was to set the border's position to static but this quite obviously isn't working when the site is centered. So to the question - is there any CSS only way to make the sidebar div's height dynamic or something and define it to expand with the content to the right? This way the border will always reach the bottom.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: can you make a fiddle with what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried fiddle but something was a mess - I'm currently using Chrome and it looks different on the fiddle. Idk why. But I think I've explained the situation. My content can get large and scroll the page in which case I need my border to stretch down and reach the bottom. That's why I think it should be something dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your navigation in another div. Give this new div a height of 100% and assign it a border-right CSS property. You can also set padding too. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about giving left border to the content section Div, instead of Nav menu. so that way the border could change height according to the content area height

Comment: Hmm, this could work although I like my content with background-color and border-radius, but I guess that I can put the content in a wrapper div and border it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
    body,html{
      height:100%;
    }

    #wrapperdiv{
      height:100%
    }

   #navigation{
      min-height:100%
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that - the problem is that when my content gets large and when I scroll down the page the border doesn't reach the bottom.

Comment: change it to min-height: 100% :)

Comment: if you could show some code might be able to see what you mean

Comment: Well that border thing is fine. I just made a parent div to the content and bordered it. But now I have another issue - my page doesn't look too good if I place the navigation bar inside the centered div. So now I centered the contend div but I can not find a way to position the navigation sidebar div to stick to the left side of the content ( I can position it for mine resolution - but that isn't working for people with other resolutions ). I actually need to float my navigation to the left side of the content ( which is positioned to the right of the navigation div )

Comment: I'm sorry, it's just I've been doing this HTML / CSS for like 2 weeks or something and I really have no idea how to explain it better, I don't know which part of my code to show you and I have problems with fiddle, so I can't give you the whole thing. That page I'm working on now is made up from 1 html file and 4 css ( 1 for the page layout and visuals, 1 for home specific css, 1 for navigation and 1 for the sidebar )

Comment: Ok, there it is: http://cssdesk.com/XMkuz. But I think I got it figured out - I placed a max-width for the html,body ( 1480px ) and centered them. Then I set my content with width 1080px and I set 200px margin from the left. It looks nice, I think I did it. Thanks to all

Comment: Alex, consider changing your HTML structure.

It should  be like this  <div id="wrapper"> <div id="sidebar"><div id="pagecontent">

Comment: Yes, I guess that is gonna make it a bit more clear to other people. It makes sense, I'll do that. Thanks